# Criptografar App.Config

Tags: c#, winforms, criptografia, app.config

Estou tentando criptografar minha *connection string*, que está no meu `app.config`.

Após ler alguns fóruns, vi que precisam ser criados 2 métodos:

```
class proteger_app
{
    public static void Criptografar()
    {
        Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        ConfigurationSection section =
            config.ConnectionStrings;

        if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider");
            section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
            config.Save();
        }
    }

    public static void Decriptografar()
    {
        Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        ConnectionStringsSection section =
            config.ConnectionStrings;

        if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
            section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
            config.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Até aí beleza, métodos criados, e depois?

```
public void chek()
    {
        string sqconn, _sql;
        int th;

        proteger_app.Decriptografar();
        sqconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql brayton"].ConnectionString;
        proteger_app.Criptografar();

        _sql = @"SELECT id FROM base64";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqconn);

        try
        {
```

Mas quando vou olhar o `app.config` está sem criptografia.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido isso. Por que você quer criptografar dentro da aplicação? O correto é fora, por linha de comando.

Comment: Haaaaaa... poderia me dar uma explicação? ou algum link que me direcione a alguma documentação? teria que criar dentro da minha aplicação, um console? e em que momento executo ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Certifique-se de que o .NET Framework está no seu PATH (aqui coloquei `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` no PATH);
- Abra um Powershell ou prompt de comando;
- Use o seguinte comando:

  ```
  > aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Caminho\Do\Seu\Projeto"
  ```

Feitos estes passos, seu `web.config` estará criptografado.

[A explicação completa está aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx).

Para descriptografar:

```
> aspnet_regiis -ped "connectionStrings" "C:\Caminho\Do\Seu\Projeto"
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Cigano, é uma aplicação winform, esse metodo que passou e para aplicação web com asp.NET certo?

Comment: Não. Qualquer aplicação.

Comment: Hum.. Depois para minha aplicação ler, normal? caso precise editar?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com a reversão da criptografia.

Comment: cara, consegui criptografar, mas agora não estou conseguindo ler a `connectionString` na minha aplicação, poderia me dar um help?

Comment: Faça outra pergunta, por favor. Coloque também o código usado (se houver) se você está usando para ler a *connection string*.

Comment: se puder dar um help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152303/app-config-como-utilizar-connectionstring-criptografada