# Criptografia Web.config e Contêiner de chaves RSA

Tags: c#, criptografia, web.config

Já foi discutido como [criptografar Web.config](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142796/criptografar-app-config), também já foi discutido como [utilizar Web.config criptografado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152303/app-config-como-utilizar-connectionstring-criptografada), porém minha duvida é o seguinte:

Caso esteja utilizando o provedor padrão `Rsa Protected Provider` para realizar a criptografia, e caso deseje ler o conteúdo do web.config em outro computador, você precisa exportar a chave do servidor onde fez a criptografia e importar para a maquina que deseja desfazer o processo.

Até ai, tudo bem, porém:

- Toda maquina que for rodar minha aplicação, preciso estar realizando a importação, isso já nos deixa uma brecha, pelo simples fato de ter a chave qualquer um pode descriptografar.

Gostaria de entender, ou se possível uma direção, de como deixar essa chave somente no meu servidor, por exemplo, quando for executar a aplicação, ela requisita para o servidor e ele retorna a `ConnectingString`.

Ou outro método para proteger a `ConnectingString` que não dependa de importação ou exportação da chave.