# Como ocultar senha do arquivo app.config?

Tags: visual-studio

Sempre que eu vou criar uma nova stringconnection, o VisualStudio me pergunta se eu quero deixar a senha vísivel no arquivo app.config

Sempre respondo que sim, pois não sei como inserí-la diretamente via código.

Como posso fazer pra excluir essa senha do arquivo e fazer a conexão em tempo de execução evitando assim que alguém abra o arquivo app.config e veja a senha lá?

Estou usando Visual Studio 2015, Entity Framework 6 e MySql

Comment: Como você não colocou nenhum contexto de código que você utiliza, verifique se te ajuda esse exemplo de criar o DBContext passando o objeto de conexão: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456849(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Você pode criptografar a connection string usando o Aspnet_regiis.exe

Comment: Se criptografar a ConnectionString lhe for suficiente, então acredito que seja duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143014/46243. Se não é isso, terá que fornecer mais detalhes nesta sua pergunta. Quando for solicitado conexão com o banco, uma tela solicitando a senha (uma vez só) é suficiente?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode encriptar a connection string utilizando o utilitário *aspnet_regiis* que está localizado em  *%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*

No caso para encriptar a seção connectio strings o comando seria 
*aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"* onde o "SampleApplication" é o nome da sua aplicação.

Assim o próprio Framework se encarregará de ler a connection string.

Mais informações [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) e exemplo do [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config)

Comment: estou usando o comando: `ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStringas" "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiConsultoria\Controle de Estoque\"` e recebo o erro: `Criptografando a seção de configuração...
Caracteres inválidos no caminho.
Falha!` o que pode ser?

Comment: Agora percebi que usei o código do link que postou e não do seu post. Vou testar agora

Comment: Usando seu código assim: `ASPNET_REGIIS -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/EstoqueFarmacia"` recebi o seguinte erro: `Criptografando a seção de configuração...
Um arquivo de configuração não pode ser criado para o objeto Configuration solicitado.
Falha!`

Comment: Faz um teste: muda o -pe para -pef e indica a pasta onde está o web.config. Só para confirmar se o erro é o mesmo

Comment: Fazendo assim: `ASPNET_REGIIS -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/EstoqueFarmacia"` são listados todos os parâmetros disponíveis, como se fosse um help

Comment: Usei assim: `ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStringas" "C:\Progra~1\WiCons~1\Contro~1\"` e assim: `ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStringas" "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiConsultoria\Controle de Estoque\"` Deu erro de `Caracteres inválidos no caminho`

Comment: O prompt de comando está sendo aberto com permissões de administrador? Seria o caso do nome da seção do web.config estar sendo passado com "connectionStringas" ao invés de "connectionStrings"?